# Where is the "default attribute" values located in the phpMyAdmin in Woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, database, phpmyadmin, customization

I'm looking to mass remove or clear the default attribute for variable products in Woocommerce.

[image]

Is there an easy way to mass clear this value? If not, would you be able to direct me on where I can find this value in phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 2):

Default attributes of WooCommerce variable products are stored as post meta in the database.
You can find them in the `wp_postmeta` table, where the `post_id` column is the post ID of the parent product (Variable product), and the `meta_key` column is `_default_attributes`.

You can clear and remove default attributes of all products by replacing all non-empty arrays.

To do so, open phpMyAdmin and select the database of your WordPress installation from the left panel and click on SQL tab. Then write the below SQL commands and press Go:

> Don't forget to backing up your database before executing any command
>   on phpMyAdmin

```
UPDATE `wp_postmeta` SET `meta_value`= 'a:0:{}' WHERE meta_key = '_default_attributes'
```

Comment: How can I change ALL products to have the attribute "fabric" by default?

Answer (score 1):

you can modify the default attribute with the following code. this code retrieve the complet list of products then it can use a big amount of ressources

```
$products = wc_get_products([
    "nopaging" => TRUE, // retrieve all products
]);


foreach ($products as $p) { 

    $default_attributes = $p->get_default_attributes();

    if (    (!empty($default_attributes))
        &&  FALSE // other condition to select of which product the default attributes is reset
    ) {

        $p->set_default_attributes("");

    }


}
```

Comment: Any particular place to run this code from?

Comment: in your function.php in your theme folder